# Consuming an ETW kernel trace using C#

Tags: c#, etw

I am using Windows Server 2012 and trying to consume a kernel trace from ETW using C#.  For example, I have a Data Collector Set entitled "LiveKernel" which has a "Windows Kernel Trace"  provider catching thread syscall events and the stream mode is Real Time.

Using [the code made available by Daniel Vasquez Lopez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielvl/archive/2009/01/25/view-etw-rewrite-events.aspx) as a starting point, I am trying to consume these events.  However, the output I receive is always just:

```
Listening...Press <Enter> to exit
```

Which to me indicates that it is not consuming any events.  My understanding of this code is that all I have to do is change the name and GUID to reflect my new choices, so I update the code to have

```
    Guid RewriteProviderId = new Guid("9E814AAD-3204-11D2-9A82-006008A86939");
    using (EventTraceWatcher watcher = new EventTraceWatcher("LiveKernel", RewriteProviderId)) {
```

Is there something I am missing here?  Is there a better way to consume a Kernel Trace?  Is there something special about the "Windows Kernel Trace" provider that prevents us from consuming events from it in real time?

Comment: Take a look at http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TraceEvent%20Class%20Overview&referringTitle=TraceEvent

Comment: This is great, and it seems to work well for the provider in the example, but I can't get it to work for the "Windows Kernel Trace" provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish want you want use the TraceEvent library from [Vance Morrison's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2013/03/09/using-traceevent-to-mine-information-in-os-registered-etw-providers.aspx). I have tested the sample on my Windows 8 running as administrator and it works perfectly.

To list each payload property name and value you need to exchange the sample delegate to the below sample.

```
Action<TraceEvent> action = delegate(TraceEvent data)
{
  foreach (var name in data.PayloadNames)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + name + " -- " + data.PayloadByName(name));
  }
};
```

Simply run the sample then start a new process and you should start seeing some trace info.

[image: Trace output when starting IE10 on Win8]

-- Lars

Comment: Thank you for this -- what you provided works great using the Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process provider and I was able to reproduce your results.  However, I also have problems getting this to work with the  "Windows Kernel Trace" provider.  I updated the code to use "Windows Kernel Provider", set the mask in enable provider to 0x1 for process, and get no data output.  Is there something special about the Windows Kernel Provider that doesn't allow me to consume events in real time?

Comment: Not to my knowledge but I have never used that provider. What events are you interested from that specific provider?

Comment: I am interested in syscall events, which AFAIK are not available from any other providers, with the exception of the "Circular Kernel Session Provider" which provides the same exact data as the Kernel Trace provider and similarly does not work using the above code.

Comment: After reading through more documentation from TraceEvent and sleeping on it, I was able to figure it out.  The key was a call to EnableKernelProvider.  Thank you for the help!